# Google Sheets, How to use AVERAGEIF with Duration criteria

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, average, weighted-average

Here is the formula I am trying to use.  Google sheets keeps giving me the Div/zero error.

```
=AVERAGEIF(G4:G1000,OR(AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(G4:G1000),{6,14,22}, 0))), ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(G4:G1000), 25, 35))
,AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(G4:G1000),{0,8,16}, 0))), ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(G4:G1000), 28, 42))
,AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(G4:G1000),{5,13,21}, 0))), ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(G4:G1000), 0, 12))
,AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(G4:G1000),{2,10,18}, 0))), ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(G4:G1000), 25, 45))),H4:H1000)
```

*edit Image of the Samplesheet
I have broken out the expression into individual parts to try and find the problem with no luck.

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Here is a sample of the data from the sheet.  I have included columns with each separate condition from the formula above.  The desired output would be the average in B3.  However I would expect a different result.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qGAwkHgkGBDEmLlqkv8vy-gy9CEqMDNHnru4_RWV3m0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Access denied [You can't access](https://i.imgur.com/IYhjpfd.png), Please [share everyone](https://i.imgur.com/Oh4SUnW.gifv), Note that your email addess is visible to anyone who accessed the sheet.

Comment: Sorry access is restricted by my organization I cannot change.  I am trying to find a work around.

Comment: Brilliant Updated the Spreadsheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B4:B, REGEXMATCH(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE((C4:G=FALSE)*1),,9^9)), "0")=FALSE))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B4:B, 0=
 ((NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(A4:A),{6,14,22}, 0))))*(ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(A4:A), 25, 35)))+
 ((NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(A4:A),{0, 8,16}, 0))))*(ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(A4:A), 28, 42)))+
 ((NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(A4:A),{5,13,21}, 0))))*(ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(A4:A), 0,  12)))+
 ((NOT(ISNA(MATCH(HOUR(A4:A),{2,10,18}, 0))))*(ISBETWEEN(MINUTE(A4:A), 25, 45)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Its a great solution, however in my actual sheet i wont have the Columns C:G
Sorry should have been more specific in the example.  I could.. maybe but don't want to add the Column G that is checking all conditions and hide the column in the final sheet.

Comment: @AaronS answer updated

Comment: Thank you, that's it.  Simple really.  haha syntax I swear